# .NET Core 6 Program.cs injecting and configuring EF Core Migrations referenced from a different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to setup a simple solution that consists of a ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api project and a .NET Core class library project using EF Core 7 and running into problems setting up the DBContext in the Program.cs file and running EF migrations.

Here is a copy of my Program.cs

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
    using MyEFCoreTestProject.EntityFrameworkCore;

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
        options =>     options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

Here is a copy of my DBContext in the other project.

```
    using Core;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

In my class library project where the DBContext exists I have the following nuget packages installed:

```
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.2
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.2
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 7.0.2
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.2
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.2
```

No matter how I attempt to run the migration I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyEFCoreTestProject.MyDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyEFCoreTestProject.MyDbContext'.
```

This is just what I have been running into while trying to do what I believe is a simple dependency registration. What I really would like to do is create a DbContext with a constructor that allows me to pass the connection string and some other flags in as parameters but my first step is just to get things working so I will have to tackle that next after this issue is solved.

Also I am not opposed to a DbContextFactory but I have been unable to find a working example that I could follow in .Net Core 6.

Any help anyone could provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is constantly being asked... Have you read the documentation on the link? It describes three ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I have read the documentation and to me not only is it incomplete but it isn't clear what to do at least not to me, thats why I am asking the question, also if the question is constantly being asked then why is it so hard to find a complete example that actually works?

Comment: The migration tool must create a DbContext for its work. To do this, it uses either Services (Host), or a constructor without parameters, or a ContextFactory. Accordingly, at least one of these three ways should be implemented in your code.